# Our country is stuck in a debt cycle..what step(even very small) can I take to help the situation get better?

Tags: gdp

Our country is stuck in debt cycle as our public revenue is far less than public expenditure thus forcing gov to   take international debts . Consequently, interest is also increasing every year and we are stuck in an debt cycle.
What (being a student) contribution can I give to help my country in this state...is there anything that can be done on my part in present??

Comment: this question is too vague, what are the parameters of an economy? What exactly will make the situation better? Just stabilizing the debt, putting the debt on some welfare maximizing level?